# set html text color and size using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have the following line of code in html, how to set the text color and size inside "MonitorInformation" DIV element in a programming way using Javascript in an easy way? Sorry for my stupid, I figured a long time but cannot figure out. :-(

```
<div id="MonitorInformation">Connecting...wait</div>
```

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Is they any reason you can't just include a rule-set for #MonitorInformation {} in your style sheet?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("MonitorInformation");
elem.innerHTML = "Setting different HTML content";
elem.style.color = "Red";
elem.style.fontSize = "large";
```

Comment: My bad, I have updated the post, I want to set size and color of text. Any ideas? :-)

Comment: Recommended to use actual values (e.g. `#FFF`, `0.7em`) instead of `Red`, `large` to stick with standards.

Answer (score 5):

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("MonitorInformation");
myDiv.style.fontSize = "11px";
myDiv.style.color = "blue";
```

Take a look at the [JavaScript Style Attributes](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javastyle.html)

Answer (score 5):

I've abstracted a few methods, which could make them a little more useful for multiple invocations:

```
var el = document.getElementById("MonitorInformation");

function text( el, str ) {
    if ( el.textContent ) {
         el.textContent = str;
    } else {
         el.innerText = str;
    }
}

function size ( el, str ) {
     el.style.fontSize = str;
}

function color ( el, str ) {
     el.style.color = str;
}

size( el, '11px') 
color( el, 'red' )
text(el, 'Hello World')
```

**Note**: The best practice to dynamically change this type of stuff would be by setting the styles in a seperate external selector:

.message { color:red; font-size:1.1em; }

And toggling the class name, .className+= 'message' ( or an abstracted function to add/remove classes ).

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#MonitorInformation").text("Hello everyone").css("color", "red")
```

Comment: My bad, I have updated the post, I want to set size and color of text. Any ideas? :-)

Comment: why everybody at stackoverflow.com giv jquery answers to javascript questions?

Comment: because they're just so accustomed to it and forgot about real dom scripting? :p

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest ways is to use a library like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com). This handles all the differences in browser JavaScript implementations for you and gives you a nice, easy API to program against.

Add a reference to jQuery using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can get a reference to your  element and modify it as follows:

```
$("#MonitorInformation").css('font-size', '2em').css('color', '#FF0000');
```

Comment: or just pass an object into the css() command with properties and values for the css properties that you want to set

Comment: pt units considered harmful - http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=UsingPoints - please don't use them in examples

Comment: @David Dorward - fair point, I've edited answer to use 'em' instead.

Comment: It's complete overkill to load an entire library for the sake of getting an element by ID and setting two style properties.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your style values are not computed in the JS, there are two seperate ways parts to this:

1. Presentation is best handled by CSS, so set up a style-rule using a class that contains the information about how you want the element to look.
2. On the elements that you want to have the appearance, use Javascript to change the class attribute to match the class in your CSS.

This has the benefits of making the JS easy - you only need to change one attribute (the class attribute is referenced with `element.className` in JS as 'class' is a reserved word). And that all the styling information is contained in one CSS file where it's easy to compare to the other styles and make changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("MonitorInformation").innerHTML = "some text";
document.getElementById("MonitorInformation").style.color = "green";
```

Comment: My bad, I have updated the post, I want to set size and color of text. Any ideas? :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
const Monitorinfo = document.queryselector('MonitorInformation');

Monitorinfo.style.color = 'red';
Monitorinfo.style.fontSize = '20px';
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.