# How to change font color in an input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts

I want to make a user-script that changes the text color inside the google search bar:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        color change
// @namespace   google
// @include     http://*.google.com
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==


var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
{
    if(inputs[i].type == "text")
    {
        inputs[i].text.css({'color' : 'red'});

    }
}
```

I pasted the following code to userscripts.org and installed it to chrome, when I visited http://google.com and started typing the text it appears black as usual where it should appear red. What did I do wrong?

Comment: inputs[i].style.color = "#FF0000";

Comment: @RajeshCP I know thanks. but why wouldn't my script work

Comment: check the console u will find it. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'css' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inputs[i].style.color = 'red';
```

userscripts are not any different than actual script in the page, you could search "change text color with js" and find this result:

[set html text color and size using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188843/set-html-text-color-and-size-using-javascript)

Comment: Can you tell me why wouldn't `.css` work? I've seen many tutorials use it.

Comment: @neomhmd: Because it's not a JavaScript method. It's a jQuery method. You are mixing jQuery and JavaScript concepts.

Comment: @neomhmd You are using the raw `HTMLInputElement` by using `document.getElementsByTagName()`. You should instead use `$("input")` to have the resulting set of nodes wrapped in a jQuery object, which allows use of `.css()`. You shouldn't need `.text`, and you'll want to use [`.get(i)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) instead of `[i]` to get a specific element from the jQuery object (if you stick with a loop, otherwise use Joel's answer). Alternatively, if the task is not going to get any more complicated that this, you shouldn't need jQuery, and Quad's answer will do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have jquery available, this seems to be a viable and possibly cleaner solution:

```
$('input').css('color', 'red');
```

The reason your example doesn't work is because it is attempting to use a jQuery method on a vanilla JavaScript object. You can't mix the two. If you want a purely vanilla solution, you need to use the recommendation by @Quad. To use jQuery, you would get rid of most of your code and replace with what I have shown above.