# Set color and size of javascript generated text

Tags: javascript, html

I am completely new to coding and am quickly getting confused. I am using the Godaddy website builder (like I said, I'm a noob) I am trying to set up a  script that will randomly output text from a list.  I have stumbled through this website enough to get:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "text1";
r_text[1] = "text2";
r_text[2] = "text3";
r_text[3] = "text4";

var i = Math.floor(5*Math.random())

document.write("<center>"+r_text[i]+"</center>");

//-->
</script>
```

This seems to work fine but the text it outputs is small and black.  I would like to increase the size of the text and change its color.  I have tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188843/set-html-text-color-and-size-using-javascript) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp) but am getting lost in exactly where to add these extra bits of code and what exactly I should use as my "h1" or "Monitor Information"?  I tried putting in r_text[i] but that seems to break things. Any advice on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a possibility of add css to your web site use a class name to your parent node and format with css like this:

```
var i = Math.floor(5*Math.random())

document.write('<div class="mytext">'+r_text[i]+'</div>');
```

and code your css like this:

```
.mytext {
   color: red;  /* or your color prefered */
   font-size: 20px;  /* size of text that you want */
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you append the text to a `div` element rather than using `document.write` and use CSS for text formatting.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nfjz5o1/1/)

#### HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "text1";
r_text[1] = "text2";
r_text[2] = "text3";
r_text[3] = "text4";

var i = Math.floor(5 * Math.random())

document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = r_text[i];
```

#### CSS:

```
div {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">

Center {
   font-size:50px;
   color:yellow;

}
</style>
```

add this to your head tag and run.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uLw92sd/1/)