# How to change the color of strings in an Array in Javascript so that it can display on the browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function

I wanted to change the colors of the strings to white so that it displays in the browser white, but I am unsure how to do that.
 I have searched high and low online and found that the font color in javascript is no longer a part of JS so Im trying to see if there are other options.

---

```
var answers = [
    'George Washington',
    'China',
    '2007',
    'DC/Maryland/Virginia',
    'Ada Lovelace'
]
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47815316/edit) to include more information.  What have you tried so far?  What source told you that "font color ... is no longer a part of JS"?  (It's not, but it is part of the DOM.)

Comment: how are you outputting your array to the browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set html text color and size using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188843/set-html-text-color-and-size-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you're displaying them as let's say using `<p>Hello</p>` , just add an ID name

`<p id="myP">Hello</p>`

and this to your JS:

```
document.getElementById("myP").style.color = "white";
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean set the text output to white?
Can do it with this: *element*.style.color = 'what ever color'